# Firefox rendering menu image incorrectly

Tags: html, css, firefox, mozilla

Hi all – I was wondering if anyone could offer any insight into a problem I am having, which I can't get my head around. Initially it was a problem with Chrome, but since having fixed that it is now with Firefox.

Check out the following left menu image. When it renders in Firefox, the "go" button hovers underneath for some reason. This does not occur in other browsers.

How it looks in Firefox:

[Firefox menu http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg254/scaled.php?server=254&filename=20212630.jpg&res=landing](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg254/scaled.php?server=254&filename=20212630.jpg&res=landing)

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yXaJE) is the HTML and CSS

I am using Firefox 14.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your stylesheet:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner, 
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner, 
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner, 
input[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: 0 none !important;
}
```

The problem is firefox puts some default padding inside of buttons and inputs. Since your search element expects a specific width, that tiny bit of padding messes it up.

The above piece of code removes that padding. It's a common piece of 'code' in many reset stylesheets.

Comment: Thanks for the code - this does work, but now the problem is occurring in Internet Explorer 9.